# Dust filters for computers

Tags: case, case-mods

Has anyone had any success in completely filtering the airflow in their computer?  If so, what materials did you use?  My room is extremely dusty, and my computer sits on the floor.  I'm having to dust it once a week to keep it fairly clean.  I want to put some foam or paper filter material that's easy to clean/replace to keep the dust down.  I saw some [fine mesh filters on Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0036WTDHK) but I want something smaller than that to trap more dust; maybe something like a paper car air filter or a polyurethane foam air conditioning filter.

If there's a product that I can try, post a link for me

If you've done it yourself, let me know what materials you used, how you affixed it to your case, how easy it is to clean, and where I can get the things

Comment: If you can raise it off the floor, even if only by six inches, it might make a significant improvement.

Answer (score 1):

Before I turned to MAC my PC was using one of the Antec P series cases, these have built in dust filters at the front as standard, or at-least mine did.

They did a great job, I didn't actually consider my room to be in a dirty/dusty environment however it really did pick up quite a bit of muck.